# nuxt route underscore param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

So the Nuxt param generation in `pages` is based on prepending an underscore `_` before a name,

Nuxt

```
pages/
--| _slug/
-----| comments.vue
-----| index.vue
--| users/
-----| _id.vue
--| index.vue
```

Vue equivalent

```
router: {
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'index',
      path: '/',
      component: 'pages/index.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'users-id',
      path: '/users/:id?',
      component: 'pages/users/_id.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'slug',
      path: '/:slug',
      component: 'pages/_slug/index.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'slug-comments',
      path: '/:slug/comments',
      component: 'pages/_slug/comments.vue'
    }
  ]
}
```

but I was wondering if it was possible to create a parameter that began with underscore. I.e. _id

E.g. /some/route/:_id

Comment: Try it and see? If I had to guess, it would be `__id.vue`

Comment: @Phil already did, it still registers it as `id`